# Different between OL > LI:only-child and !OL > LI:only-child CSS Selector 4?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

For example, the following selector represents a list item LI unique child of an ordered list OL:

```
OL > LI:only-child
```

However the following one represents an ordered list OL having a unique child, that child being a LI:

```
!OL > LI:only-child
```

The tree structures represented by these two selectors are the same, but the subjects of the selectors are not.

i am not understand this different can you give me example

Comment: The second selector looks like [CSS4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/) to me. I'm pretty sure it's still being drafted. The difference is that the second one is selecting the parent.

Comment: yes you right @JoshCrozier ....

Comment: @user1153551 When you unaccept an answer, please precise why in comment.

Comment: @dystroy not any large reason. but this is drafted so now not need for this information. also not support any browser so i thing i should remove. what about you say ?

Answer (score 3):

Your example is taken from [the W3C's draft](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/selectors4/#subject).

The difference is the element on which the rule applies.

In the first case, it's the `LI`, because by default the rule applies to the last element of the selector.

In the second case, it's the `OL`, which holds the `!`.

Supposing you have this style :

```
!OL > LI:only-child {
   background: yellow;
}
```

then the background will be applied to the whole OL.

Comment: 1+ I'm curious as to whether or not `!` will be published.. I'd think that the *pseudo* ability to transverse the DOM would have an effect on performance, though i'm sure it will be minimal.

Comment: @JoshCrozier I don't know more than you. And I'm dubious too regarding wether it's a good idea to put into CSS selectors which can be so heavy.

Comment: I think the authors should replace the `!` mark with something else as `!OL` seems like `:not(OL)`.